# What's the best workaround to automatically bcc in an email address when sending an email from an SF Case?

Tags: email

I am trying to have it so any emails sent from SF on a Case Record are bcc'd to an email address (e.g. supportteam@mycompany.com)

I know that there's no way currently to automatically bcc in an email address (e.g. supportteam@mycompany.com) when sending an email from SF (other than the Compliance BCC for everything, or the individual user's own email address), and the [idea for control on Workflows/etc](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrEkAAK) is still trying to get traction (please upvote!), but does anyone have a workaround?

I've tried Process Builder and it doesn't forward the Email Message...I can only create an Email Alert to the email (e.g. supportteam@mycompany.com) to advise an email message has been sent from the case.

Does anyone have a workaround that allows you to EITHER:
- bcc in an email address (e.g. supportteam@mycompany.com) to all Emails sent from SF from a Case record, OR
- fwd all Emails, including attachments) sent from SF from a Case record to another email address (e.g. supportteam@mycompany.com)

The only alternative I've been able to come up with is to set up the other email address (e.g. supportteam@mycompany.com) as a Chatter User and set their Chatter notifications up, then do a Process Builder to create a Chatter post.  But, the content of the email message is sometimes really long and doesn't pull through very well.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  With a support team based around the world, this will be useful to share case correspondence and updates, and allow support staff to jump in and work collaboratively with the customer without having to proactively go to the Case and read through the Email Messages.

​​​​​​​Cheers, Nat

(Have also logged in [SF Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ikQlQAI#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Email&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=9063A000000lb7OQAQ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no standard way, but you can try to send the email with apex class using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

for example:
Some methods in class
setBccAddresses(bccAddresses)
setCcAddresses(ccAddresses)
setHtmlBody(htmlBody)

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

Thanks & Regards,
​​​​​​​Sakthivel Madesh